# InStr to return ENTIRE criteria not partials

Tags: excel, vba

My code below does not return the EXACT value from a list of names.  For example if in a list I have:

Ann
Anna
Hannah

...and I am looking for "Hannah Fawler" the code will return the following:

"Ann, Anna, Hannah"

I need to update the code to look for the ENTIRE name (Hannah) in a cell (which will have comments and will mention the persons full name) and return the ENTIRE name with no partials (Hannah > Hannah).  Anyone know how to do this?

```
Public Function NameLister(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As String
    Dim Sentence As String
    NameLister = ""
    Sentence = LCase(r2.Text)
    For Each r In r1
        v = LCase(r.Text)
        If v <> "" Then
            If InStr(1, Sentence, v) > 0 Then
                If NameLister = "" Then
                    v = StrConv(v, vbProperCase)
                    NameLister = v
                Else
                    v = StrConv(v, vbProperCase)
                    NameLister = NameLister & ", " & v
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses a VBScript regular expression object. It matches the entire name (no partials) by requiring the name to appear within word boundaries (`\b` in regular expressions).

```
Public Function NameLister(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As String
    Dim Sentence As String, rgx As Object
    NameLister = ""
    Sentence = LCase(r2.Text)
    'Initialize regular expression object
    Set rgx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    For Each r In r1
        v = LCase(r.Text)
        If v <> "" Then
            'Set search pattern to match only entire word.
            rgx.Pattern = "\b" & v & "\b"
            'Test Sentence for matches
            If rgx.Test(Sentence) Then
                If NameLister = "" Then
                    v = StrConv(v, vbProperCase)
                    NameLister = v
                Else
                    v = StrConv(v, vbProperCase)
                    NameLister = NameLister & ", " & v
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

Comment: The solution supplied by **Excellll** looks good.  If you REALLY want to stick with **InStr()** , you would need to use " Hannah " rather than "Hannah"..........means either modifying the table in the worksheet or modifying the sub to do the same thing.

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thank you all for you help

Comment: @tuft1985 If your question is answered fully, please use the green check-mark at the left side to mark this answer as accepted. That's how this site works.